# validate a number in JSON

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

Following is my JSON object. It contains a `string` for `name` and `int` for `age`.

Based on the following code, everything works fine. However, If i add a random `string`to  `age` ex: "ABC". The `DeserializeObject` code throws an exception, and I am not able to validate the `if (ani.age > 0)`.

How am I going to ever validate `age` if the `DeserializeObject` throws an error ?

```
"animal": {
  "name":"xxs",
  "age": 23
}

   Animal ani = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Animal>(anim]);

  if (ani.age > 0) return true;
```

Comment: by catching the exception? why age may become string?

Comment: Wouldn't that be part of the validation, checking if the response is in the format you expect it to be?

Answer (score 2):

If catching and handling an exception is not good enough for you, I advise you to use JsonSchema and validate given string against defined schema.

```
string schemaJson = @"{
      'description': 'Animal',
      'type': 'object',
      'properties':
      {
        'name': {'type':'string'},
        'age': {'type': 'number'}
      }
    }";

JsonSchema schema = JsonSchema.Parse(schemaJson);

JObject animal = JObject.Parse(@"{
  'name': 'ani',
  'age': '12'
}");

bool valid = animal.IsValid(schema);
valid.Dump(); // outputs False
```

Note: JsonSchema is [obsoleted](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/N_Newtonsoft_Json_Schema.htm) inside Json.Net library, however there is standalone JsonSchema [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json.Schema/)

Besides that, you can create custom [converters](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverterGeneric.htm) and handle such cases gracefully, for example do manual conversion from "12" to 12 and deserialize properly.

Based on the comment, I suggest you to catch the exception and handle it:

```
try
{           

    Animal animal= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Animal>(@"{
      'name': 'ani',
      'age': 'ABC'
    }");

    // deserialization was successful, proceed with business process...
}
catch (JsonReaderException ex)
{
    //Could not convert string to integer: abc. Path 'age', line 3, position 16.
    // take the string from ex.Message and transform into validation error message sent do the user
}
```

Comment: How can i identified each attribute. If `age` is a string I need to catch it and throw a custom error message.